# "SQL error or missing data type near WHERE syntax" when trying to UPDATE SQLite

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, sql-update

I got a problem and I can't find the error. It doesnt let me update my index and always says `SQL error or missing data type near WHERE syntax`. Everything else works. So I thought you guys could have a look at this:

`Create Table: execute("CREATE TABLE Players (player TEXT, money DOUBLE, job TEXT, level INTEGER, exp DOUBLE)");` **Works**

`Insert: DATABASE.execute("INSERT INTO Players VALUES ('" + player + "', " + money + ", '" + job.getJob() + "', " + job.getLevel() + ", " + job.getEXP() + ")");` **Works**

`Update: DATABASE.execute("UPDATE Players WHERE player = '" + player.toLowerCase() + "' SET money = " + money + ", job = '" + job.getJob() + "', level = " + job.getLevel() + ", exp = " + job.getEXP());` **Doesnt work**

I am using the following values to Update:

```
player = gemaken
money = 100.0
job.getJob() = miner
level = 0
exp = 0.0
```

Thanks in advance!

Sincerely,
Gemaken

Comment: First thing to do: stop building SQL like that. Use a PreparedStatement, and your SQL will be *much* easier to read... and you won't be inviting a [SQL Injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL `UPDATE`, the `SET` part comes first and the `WHERE` part only later:

```
DATABASE.execute("UPDATE Players SET money = " + money + ", job = '" + job.getJob() + "', level = " + job.getLevel() + ", exp = " + job.getEXP()) + " WHERE player = '" + player.toLowerCase() + "';
```

Also, consider using parameters and prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
Update: DATABASE.execute("UPDATE Players SET money = " + money + ", job = '" + job.getJob() + "', level = " + job.getLevel() + ", exp = " + job.getEXP() WHERE player = '" + player.toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason behind your update query to give error is the incorrect syntax of the UPDATE query. Follow the syntax as in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms177523.aspx) or [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html)

**Your query should be like this:**

`DATABASE.execute("UPDATE Players SET money=" + money + ", job='" + job.getJob() + "', level=" + job.getLevel() + ", exp=" + job.getEXP() + " WHERE player='" + player.toLowerCase() + "'")`